# Best way to compare multiple string in java

Tags: string, compare

Suppose I have a string "That question is on the minds of every one.". 
I want to compare each word in string with a set of word I.e. (to , is ,on , of) and if those word occurs I want to append some string on the existing string.

Eg.
 to = append "Hi";
Is = append "Hello";

And so on.

To be more specific I have used StringTokenizer  to get the each word and compared thru if else statement. However we can use Switch also but it is available in Jdk 1.
7.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Don't expect people on StackOverflow to just give you working code if you haven't showed any effort or don't ask a more specific question.

Comment: @MartinDinov  I have tried with if else statement and achived desired outpot also , However I dont thinks it is best way..

Comment: Alright, I've given you an answer that makes use of a HashMap. See below.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is what you mean, but:

You could use `String.split()` to separate the words from your string like

```
String[] words = myString.split(" ");
```

and then, for each word, compare it with the given set

```
for(String s : words)
{
  switch(s)
 {
   case("to"): 
   [...]
 }
}
```

Or you could just use the `String.contains()` method without even splitting your string, but I don't know if that's what you wanted.

Answer (score 0):

Use a `HashMap<String,String>` variable to store your set of words and the replacement words you want. Then split your string with `split()`, loop through the resulting `String[]` and for each `String` in the `String[]`, check whether the `HashMap` `containsKey()` that `String`. Build your output/resulting `String` in the loop - if the word is contained in the `HashMap`, replace it with the value of the corresponding key in the `HashMap`, otherwise use the `String` you are currently on from the `String[]`.